# Highlight boolean array on a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot a graph (time, velocity), and need to filter values lower than 14.0 and highlight those values in a graph.

```
# IV-T

diffhor = np.diff(xframe)
diffvert = np.diff(yframe)
vel = np.sqrt((diffhor**2)+(diffvert**2))

filteredvel = flt.savgol_filter(vel, 70, 2)

fixations = np.zeros_like(filteredvel, dtype=bool)
fixations[filteredvel <= 14.0] = True

# plot velocity over time

plt.plot(timeframe[0:-1], fixations)
plt.xlabel('time (ms)')
plt.ylabel('velocity signal')
plt.title('IV-T')
plt.show()
```

So here it does plot the fixations (values lower than 14.0), but only as 0 and 1's, since it is a boolean array. Is there a way to plot time, filteredvel so that all True values in fixations are highlighted in the graph?

Answer (score 0):

found it:

```
fixations = fixations * filteredvel

fixations[fixations == 0] = np.nan
```

now if I plot this in red over the original graph, it correctly shows all values under 14.0